# android inputType="number" and "numberPassword" different keyboards, how to make same keyboards?

Tags: android

When in EditText xml layout I set `android:inputType="number"` I see one keyboard, with dash, dot and comma.
When I set `android:inputType="numberPassword"` I see another keyboard, only numbers this time.

How do I show keyboard with only numbers, without dot and comma, for a non-password EditText?

Comment: Use : android:inputType="numberPassword"

Comment: @strada android Was the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

if you need only numbers then best option for you would be `android:inputType="numberSigned"`

and the keyboard... well, in fact keyboard style doesn't depend on you... this is another separated app installed in system and it try to fit `inputType` of `EditText`. some keyboard apps may have different buttons for `inputType="number"` and `inputType="numberPassword"`, some other may have same UI, yet some other may just have one UI with all buttons for all `inputTypes` (thus some of these buttons may be inactive, e.g. letters when digit-only `inputType`)

even when your keyboard app provides different keyboard style doesn't mean that on another device with another keyboard app this behavior will be the same

Answer (score 1):

you can join 2 types in inputType EditText in android

this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) all type for EditText

for example you can use :

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

or

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```